fontspec crashes with undefined control sequence from \strongfontdeclare
I'm trying to switch from pdflatex to xelatex.
My environment is

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS,
MikTeX 23.4, and
xetex 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995.

When I run xelatex on
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}

I get this error
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \prop_gput_if_not_in:Nnn 
                                         \g__fontspec_strong_prop {m}{0}
l.4227 \strongfontdeclare{\bfseries}

Can this possibly be user error?
How much simpler could my input file be?

Please post your .log file. Did you install fontspec manually? Because you seem to have a newer version of fontspec and an older version of LaTeX. (Specifically, an older version of the expl3 programming layer.) Your log will show this, if so.

Check for updates in the miktex console in user and admin mode.

@UlrikeFischer, why the heck didn't I think of that?

@UlrikeFischer I have a similar situation except in a portable Windows 10  installation for which admin mode doesn't exist. fontspec 2024/05/11 v2.9e; expl3 2024-01-04; xparse 2023-10-10.  This all from a brand new installation downloaded yesterday (24.1). What should I do ? :) ("Administrator mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup")

@JulianMoore then check for updates in user mode. Your expl3 is too old.

@UlrikeFischer Done: several OPTIONAL updates clearly not all optional. Resolved. No expl3 per se but l3backend l3kernel and l3packages installed. Thx

l3kernel (+ l3backend + l3packages) is expl3.

All it took was an update from the MikTeX console [he reported sheepishly].
